# replace variable by string

Tags: php, sql

i have this code

```
$sql3 = mysql_query (" ") ;
while($row3 =mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {
  $sql4 = mysql_query (" SELECT $ww as yourplace FROM data WHERE $ww = 
     ".$row3[$ww]." and id_user = ".$userid." ");
  $row4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql4) ;
  $string = "<< You Here" ;
  echo "<tr><td width='100'>Week ".$row3[$ww]."</td>" ;
  echo "<td width='300' >".(int) $row3["percent"] ."%</td>";
  echo "<td width='300' > "?><?php echo $row4['yourplace'] ;?><?php "</td></tr>";
}
```

how to replace `$row4['yourplace']` in line 10 by the `$string` in line 6 .

now `$row4['yourplace']` appears only in specific line in table , so when i use this code

```
$row4['yourplace'] = $string ;
```

this will replace but will appear in all lines in the table. so i want to be replaced and appears in the specified lines also .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure about your if condition but you would probably like to do something like this,

```
echo "<td width='300' > "?><?php if($sql4) echo $string else $row4['yourplace'] ;?><?php "</td></tr>";
```

You can replace $sql4 with whatever condition your code has.

**UPDATE:**

Here's what you can do,

```
if($row4[$ww] == $row3[$ww] && $row4['id_user'] == $userid )
 echo $string ;
else 
echo "";
```

Comment: i have already said if i do like that , read the last 2 lines

Comment: Unfortunately the last 2 lines are not clear. Can you explain it ? And secondly, can you mention the criteria on which you are deciding that when $row4 is assigned to $string and when it's not ?

Comment: ok if i replace directly by this string , it will echo this string in all lines of the table . but if not replaced my variable will echo only in specified lines in the table , so i want to replace this variable by this string but will echo in the specified lines also in the table , hope its clear now

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me the condition when you want the $string to appear ?

Comment: Just make sure that you are not using $sql4 but an actual condition, whatever your condition will be, $string will appear accordingly.

Comment: i have make it like that `if($row4['$ww']= ".$row3[$ww]." && $row4['id_user'] = ".$userid." ){ echo $string ; } else { echo "";}`

Comment: That's an assignment statement and not a check statement. Updated my answer.

Comment: I believe that you are probably not writing your if statement correctly. But this is the way to do what you want to do. You can check it by just placing both true and false in your statement eg. if(true) and then if(false). Best of luck!